# why does my code appear as a black screen on pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am new at coding. I have been trying to load a picture to modify it as a tutorial and it keeps appearing as a black screen. I do not know where is problem, and what I'm missing, so any advice on that would be appreciated as well.

```
import sys

import pygame

import random

command = sys.argv[1]

img = pygame.image.load(command)

(wid, hgt) = img.get_size()

new_img = pygame.display.set_mode(((wid) * 4, (hgt) * 4)).convert()

img.blit (new_img,(0,0))

for x in range(wid ):
    for y in range(hgt):
    
        (r,g,b,_) = new_img.get_at((x,y))
        lum = (0.2126 *r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0788 * b)/255
        a = int(r/4)
        b = int(g/4)
        c = int(b/4)
    
        while(a > 0):
            if(lum > 0.667):
                pygame.draw.rect(new_img,(255,0,0),(random.randint((x*50),           
                (x*50)),random.randint((y*50),(y*50))1,1)
                a-=1
    
        while(b > 0):
            if(lum > 0.334):
                pygame.draw.rect(new_img,(0,255,0),(random.randint((x*4), 
                (x*4)),random.randint((y*4),(y*4))1,1)
                k-=1
        while(d > 0):
            if(lum > 0.001):
                pygame.draw.circle(new_img,(0,0,255),(random.randint((x*4), 
                (x*4)),random.randint((y*4),(y*4))),1,1)
                d-=1


pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `blit` the image (`ìmg) on the display (`new_img`). The display is` new_img`not`img`.

<s>`img.blit (new_img,(0,0))`</s>

```py
new_img.blit(img, (0, 0))
```

I recommend to change the name of the display *Surface*:

```py
import sys
import pygame
import random

command = sys.argv[1]
img = pygame.image.load(command)
(wid, hgt) = img.get_size()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(((wid) * 4, (hgt) * 4)).convert()

# draw background on screen
screen.blit(img, (0, 0))

# draw tiles on screen
for x in range(wid ):
    for y in range(hgt):
    
        (r,g,b,_) = img.get_at((x,y))
        lum = (0.2126 *r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0788 * b)/255
        a = int(r/4)
        b = int(g/4)
        c = int(b/4)
    
        while(a > 0):
            if(lum > 0.667):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0),(random.randint((x*50),           
                (x*50)),random.randint((y*50),(y*50))1,1)
            a-=1
    
        while(b > 0):
            if(lum > 0.334):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0),(random.randint((x*4), 
                (x*4)),random.randint((y*4),(y*4))1,1)
            d-=1
        while(d > 0):
            if(lum > 0.001):
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255),(random.randint((x*4), 
                (x*4)),random.randint((y*4),(y*4))),1,1)
            d-=1


pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I changed my code for check, but it's frozen... I do not know why